# Two different Cell Types in one UITableView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Hey everybody, I'm very confused about how to use two different Cell Types in one UITableView with two sections. The first section should return a large Cell, with a lot of text, the other section should return three cells, to navigate to other Views. I tried it like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //NSUInteger section;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"CellIdentifier";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell";

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        CustomTableCell *cell = (CustomTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableCell" owner:self options:nil];     cell = [self customTableCell];
            [self setCustomTableCell:nil];
        }
        return cell;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1) {

            cTableViewCell *cell = (cTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"cTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [[cTableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
                [self setCustomTableCell:nil];
            }
            // Configure the cell...
            NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
            cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:row];
            return cell;            
        }
    return cell;
}
```

I set the height for the cells in the sections here:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger section;
    if (section == 0) {
        return [indexPath row] + 80;
    }
    else 
    {
        return [indexPath row] + 44;
    }

}
```

I get this Error: 'cell' undeclared (first use this function). :( I really hope that you could help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, make it `return nil;` instead of `return cell;`.

Comment: It would be better to declare `cell` outside of the if-else statement, e.g., `UITableViewCell *cell;`, and remove both `return cell` statements from the if-else statement, and just `return cell` at the end of the method. If `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` ever returns `nil`, UIKit throws an exception.

Comment: @MattDiPasquale in my tableview data is getting shuffled when scroll, but when i set dequereuable feature to nil then it works, nut data is dynamic so i don't want to use nil, is there any other way for this. Please help man.