# Load two different nibs in one UITableView on iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, load, nib

I have a problem loading different nib files in one tableView. I saw this similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089857/two-different-cell-types-in-one-uitableview). Unfortunately it doesn't help me.

What I need is to be able to load firstNib for first x cells and load secondNib for last n-x cells. I know that if I put `if` clause inside `if (cell == nil)` than there is a problem with reusing cells - first x cells gets repeated after m cells.

Could someone please explain it to me how can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a different reuse identifier for each type of cell - set the reuse identifier depending on the row number, then dequeue / load the specific type of cell.